# Facing an issue with Laravel Vite where it keeps reloading the page constantly

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, vite

https://streamable.com/w6o5uc

I've recorded a video to best explain the issue. Basically I just bought a new PC, so I did a fresh install of everything, from node/npm to php. And when I ran my project (that works fine on my Laptop) - I'm facing this issue where whenever I try to open a new page or the page refreshes, it keeps refreshing. I've also tried different browsers, but it seems to be a Laravel Vite issue. As you can see in the video, it just keeps making new dynamic views.

I'd really love some help.

Here's my Vite config if its relevant. The issue DOESN'T appear when I run my Laravel project without `npm run dev` but as soon as I do and I hit reload on ANY page - it just keeps reloading again & again, after every 500ms or so.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel, { refreshPaths } from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: [
                ...refreshPaths,
                'app/Livewire/**',
            ],
        }),
    ],
});
```

Comment: Are the versions of node and vite the same on your PC as on your laptop?

Comment: I believe not. My laptop has Node v18 and PC has the LTS version of Node that the website recommends.

Comment: Oh it's possible that this version difference might be a contributing factor to the issue you're facing. You should try using nvm and match the pc version to laptop i.e. 18. Then remove your node modules and package-lock/yarn-lock.json and reinstall dependencies

Comment: I'll check it out, try downgrading again and get back to you. Thanks.